# Arduino & xbee - what is needed?

Tags: arduino, wireless, xbee

Okay, so I am completely confused now. First off, I just purchased two xbee units and the pin spacing does not match up with a breadboard .. so I need more hardware.

Anyway, this is what I have:

XBee 2mW PCB Antenna - Series 2

XBee Explorer USB

---

What else is needed? What is the best way to interface the second xBee (not on the explorer/computer side) ? What kind of board?

With this board: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11373
Do you just solder some header pins on the underside of it?

As an aside: Is there anything within a reasonable price range that you would suggest gettingh from SparkFun? I might as well purchase something else that I will probably end up using since I will get charged the same freight either way

Comment: You should never, ever assume anything will fit on a breadboard.

Comment: The XBee uses 2 mm pitch connectors. Breadboards are typically 2.54 mm pitch. The Arduino headers are 2.54 mm pitch too, but most of them (except the Nano, Micro and perhaps a couple of others) are not directly breadboard friendly because of an offset between headers in each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a shield (for the XBEE modem) that plugs into the arduino:
https://www.google.ca/search?q=xbee+shield+arduino

Then you need the X-CTU program from Digi, version 5.2.7.5 or newer to configure the XBEE modems. Make sure you download the manual as well. 
Sparkfun seems to have links to the program.

The "As an aside" question... Decide what you want to do/experiment with and you can answer your own question. But what I have found helpful is to buy a set of resistors of many values. They are cheap and cheaper in bulk. Capacitors as well, and if you plan to drive higher loads than the output of the arduino can handle, buy a few MOSFETs to use as drivers.